# JAVA JSONObject with prepared data

Tags: java, android, json

Sorry, I started teach java few days ago and didn't find a solution in google.
I know that I can do this:

```
JSONOblect x = new JSONObject;
JSONOblect y = new JSONObject;
y.put("a","b");
x.put("c",y);
```

I just want to ask is there any way to add one object into other something like

```
JSONObject x = new JSONObject();
x.put("c", new JSONObject{"a":"b"});
```

I have a lot of objects one inside other and if I declare each as variable - it will be very long.

Comment: There are many, many different versions of JSONObject. Which JSON library are you using? Whatever the library is, I'm sure it can parse JSON.

Comment: I started teach android development. So it is already in ADT.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29. The constructor you're looking for is right there, in the documentation. You MUST learn to read the documentation.

Comment: Thanx. I'll read it right now )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `org.json.JSONObject`, you can use the fact that `JSONObject.put` returns the value it's called on. For example:

```
JSONObject x = new JSONObject().put("c", new JSONObject().put("a", "b"));
```

You might want to consider embedding the data *as JSON* into your application though, and just parsing it. Aside from anything else, that's considerably easier to read and modify...

Comment: O, this is much better, thanx! Yes, I use org.json.JSONObject